# how to have 8 or 9 digit + DDD phone mask using react imask?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, imaskjs

I'm using lib react imask to add mask to my inputs. In case of phone, it can support numbers with 8 or 9 digits. How can I resolve this dynamically?

8 digits -> mask  '(00) 0000-0000'
9 digits -> mask  '(00) 00000-0000'

```
const mask = {
  mask: '(00) 00000-0000'
};

const InputPhone: React.FC<InputProps> = (props) => {
  return <InputMask maskParams={mask} name='phone' {...props} />;
};
```

Comment: https://imask.js.org/guide.html#masked-dynamic

Comment: my input already accepts 8 or 9 digits. I just want to change the mask depending on the number of digits.

Answer (score 2):

Refer this: https://imask.js.org/guide.html#masked-dynamic

```
import { IMaskInput } from 'react-imask';

const mask = [{ mask: '(00) 0000-0000' }, { mask: '(00) 00000-0000' }];

const Home = () => (
  <IMaskInput mask={mask} name="phone" placeholder="Enter phone number here" />
);

export default Home;
```

Output:

[image]

[image: Open in StackBlitz]

Comment: thanks my friend, but it doesn't work in typescrit

Comment: @BryanLima That's because their types are completely useless https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-imask@6.2.2/dist/input.d.ts. Create an issue on their github (PS: actually there are already - https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs/issues/554, https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs/issues/581). You need to manually override types meanwhile or use an ignore comment.